terraform wafv2 error - unsupported block rule_action_override
I am trying to get rid of exclude rule and use dynamic rule to overide waf rule config in aws firewall. I keep getting the error unsupported dynamic "rule_action_override". this bothering for a while now. refrred hashicorp and some git tickets for same issue no luck.
  managed_rule_group_statement {
          name        = rule.value.name
          vendor_name = rule.value.vendor_name
          #version     = rule.value.version

          dynamic "rule_action_override" {

            for_each = rule.value.rule_action_override
            content {
              name = rule_action_override.value["name"]
              action_to_use {
                dynamic "allow" {
                  for_each = rule_action_override.value["action_to_use"] == "allow" ? [1] : []
                  content {}
                }
                dynamic "block" {
                  for_each = rule_action_override.value["action_to_use"] == "block" ? [1] : []
                  content {}
                }
                dynamic "count" {
                  for_each = rule_action_override.value["action_to_use"] == "count" ? [1] : []
                  content {}
                }
              }
            }
          }

Terraform an provider version
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.76.1"
    }
    venafi = {
      source = "venafi/venafi"
      version = "0.15.5"
    }
  }  
}


Could it be that the provider version is very old?

the dcoument of hashicorp not clear which provider version to use for this waf keyword upgrade

Well, from what I can see for that provider version, no such option exists: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.76.1/docs/resources/wafv2_web_acl.

no option in the version your link is pointing. 3.76. lookin in higher versions from the drop down above in same page page.

Based on your configuration, you have pinned the version to version = "3.76.1".
